# Подскажите где ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.6, telebot

По команде `/add` бот должен спросить и записать две переменные: "Date" и "Name".
Все работает до строчки:

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter a name:")
del message.text`

Появляется строка: "enter a name:" и после моего ответа, вместо продолжения кода снова появляется "enter a name:" и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add_birthdate(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You entered in add module")
    if message.text == "/add" : 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter a date (day-month):")
        del message.text

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def add_date (message):
    date = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter a name:")
    del message.text

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def add_name (message):
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением:

**`bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_name)`**

Код принял такой вид:

```
import telebot  
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add_birthdate(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You entered in add module")
    if message.text == "/add" : 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter a date (day-month):")  

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def add_date(message):
        global date
        date = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter a name:")    
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_name) 
        return date


    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def add_name(message):
        global name
        name = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Data have been download! \n Enter /start to continue.")
        return name
```